# mysql varchar(11) like '201158503123' change to '2.01E+10' when put it into Excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I want to get something form mysql and put it into Excel,but all the number like "201158503123"change to "2.01E+10",the number of type in mysql is varchar(11)..who
can help me...

Comment: I assume you're exporting from MySQL as CSV?  See http://superuser.com/questions/234997/how-can-i-stop-excel-from-eating-my-delicious-csv-files-and-excreting-useless-da

Answer (score 3):

1. Right-click the range
2. Format Cells
3. Number tab
4. Number (*Decimal Places:* 0)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much,i find the cell is too narrow，then i spin the cell，it is change normal。。。

Comment: SmallEarth, please mark @Danny answer as completed.  Thank you!